# When is code in Scala objects evaluated?

Tags: scala

Could someone explain to me why given the object:

```
object HelloWord {
  println("hello world")
  var z = 1
  z += {
    println("adding 1 to z")
    1
  }
}
```

running the following code in the REPL gives:

```
import HelloWorld._
// no output
z
// hello world
// adding 1 to z
// res0: Int = 2
z
// res1: Int = 2
```

To clarify, I would like an explanation of the output for each line of code entered into the REPL.

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scala objects are initialized lazily; their top-level code will be executed once when the object is first loaded and used.

Importing a class does not cause it to be loaded, so nothing happens.

Evaluating `z` in the REPL causes the object's class to be loaded and the initialization code to be executed. This will only happen once, just like a static initializer in Java.

Evaluating `z` again in the REPL prints out the value from the previous initialization. The initialization code is not run again, so neither of the `println` statements is executed.